# How does svm deal with new levels of a variable added over time when considering time series data?

Tags: time-series, machine-learning, svm

I am trying to predict customer spending for an X year period after t0. I train an svm model with transactions occurring before and on t0, on the cumulative spending of the customers after t0. I then use the model to make predictions on a test data set to assess the models accuracy. The test dataset is from 1 period (in the example below 1 day) in the future. How does an svm deal with newly acquired customers?

**Question elaboration:**

My training data is structured as follows:

```
>DT1
   Id t.-3 t.-2 t.-1 t.0 Target.spending
1:  1   29   25   14  25             100
2:  2   NA   30    0   0               0
3:  3   NA   16    0  13               0
4:  4   NA   NA   62  18               5
```

Customer 1 was acquired on t.-3 when he purchased worth 29$. His second purchase occurred on t.-2. etc... Customer 2 was acquired on t.-2 and only purchased on that day. Target.spending is the cumulative spending that occurred in the next four days (i.e. t.1+t.2+t.3+t.4).

Then, I predict the spending of the next four days using an svm:

```
train.model <- svm(Target.spending ~ . , data = DT)
```

Using a test data set from one day in the future (where t.0 (DT1) = t.-1 (DT2)), I will predict the target.spending (DT2) and assess the model accuracy. In the test data, on t.0 (DT2), customer 5 was acquired.

```
>DT2
   Id t.-3 t.-2 t.-1 t.0 Target.spending
1:  1   25   14   25  10             103
2:  2   30    0    0   0               0
3:  3   16    0   13   0               0
4:  4   NA   62   18   4               1
5:  5   NA   NA   NA   9              30
```

How does the svm deal with new customer acquisitions?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used it, but I am pretty sure you have add a parameter when running the training to say that you have a regression problem not a classification problem.

I also think SVM will just interpret NA as 0 and push that through the projection. So it will interpret a new customer the same way as an old one, who did not buy anything in all your time periods.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What if I use `Id` as an independent variable? The model is trained on `Id` (factor) with 4 levels (1,2,3,4) but the test dataset has 5 levels (1,2,3,4,5). How will the effect of the 5th customer be taken into consideration? (This is not so relevant when each customer has 1 row, but when I introduce lagged data each customer will have multiple rows)